# AH01630: client denied by server configuration WAMP

Tags: wamp

I have seen alot alot of guides how to fox the AH01630 error and some httpd corrections and tweaks.
Surely some will be annoyed me asking for help on this specific topic but I was trying to figure out for hours how to fix my issue.

What did I do?

I have port-forwarded the required ports for Apache and MySQL

I installed WAMP on my computer

I tried to config. httpd

I read about 50 topics according to make my server public accessible
    -

I tried to set up the whole thing on a fresh virtual machine

I reinstalled WAMP a few times

So what doesn't work?

The usual access refuse message: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
   -I found this in the error log: AH01630: client denied by server configuration

I have tried to fix the issue by my own and couldn't proceed further after hours, maybe I forgot a little detail or just something I have to know but I don't because I am uneducated in this specific area

Thanks in advance

Here are the logs and config, if you don't mind and know how to fix the problem send me the finished file

[httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/ZDDnSFYS)

apache_error.log http:// pastebin. com/YSZDc0tp

access.log  http:// pastebin. com/xfwv5ebB

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you using?

Answer (score 7):

In WAMPServer 3+ there is a Virtual Host defined for localhost by default, and that is where you should make the access amendments and not in `httpd.conf`

So in `httpd.conf` replace

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

With

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
</Directory>
```

Edit `\wamp\bin\apache\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` and replace `Require local` with `Require all granted`

**EG**

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@homemail.net
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot E:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "E:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```