# WampServer 3 Online Forbidden

Tags: wamp, wampserver, lan

When I try to access my local website from another device (connected with LAN), I get Forbidden error.

I tried to edit Apache's httpd.conf (as what google told me), repair vcredist packages, uninstalling wamp completely and installing (re-downloaded the latest version), deactivating Antivirus software (I am using BitDefender btw).

About 1 month ago, I was using windows 7 and wamp was working perfectly. After I upgraded to windows 10, I cleaned my pc and installed wamp. At first, I didn't need it's Online mode, but right now, I need it. So, I am open to all new ideas.

Note

-I can reach localhost with my pc (with LAN IP, Router IP and http://localhost)

-I am using Windows 10 Professional x64

### -I looked at all of the similar questions and relevant pages on Google, and none of them worked for me

About 3 weeks ago, I started using a new router. Can it cause this problem? or maybe I couldn't install drivers correctly?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624031/ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration-wamp/38664545#38664545

Answer (score 7):

don't edit http.config instead edit httpd-vhosts.config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

change **Require local** to **Require all granted**. when it is Require local it can be accessed only through localhost request from other hosts are denied. Finally it looks like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```